# Why does the Material-UI Select does not display any option?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

Hello I was changing all my selects to Material-UI Selects (because they look better in my opinion) , but I'm struggling because I'm looking at a tutorial and I have exactly the same settings but I don't see any of the options I have set up

[image]

```
const [escuela, setEscuela] = useState("");

const handleChange2 = (event) => {
      setEscuela(event.target.value);
    };

<Select className= "SelectMultiple" value = {escuela} label = "Seleccione Escuela..." onChange={handleChange2}>
<MenuItem value={"Academia Internacional de Boquete"}>Academia Internacional de Boquete</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={"Academia Internacional de David"}>Academia Internacional de David</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: You are using MUI's `Select` but the `Select` in the screenshot is from `react-select` package.

Comment: no, Select is from MUI, select is react-select. I'm literally using it on other piece of code but with multiselect and not having issues.

Comment: Change `setGrado` to `setEscuela`, it should work.

Comment: no it doesn't sorry it was just a typo. (I have 2 and using the shortest one cause the other one has like 15 options)

Comment: What version of MUI are you using?

Comment: last one available

Comment: You have another typo, change `handleChange2` to `handleChange1`?

Comment: yeah just did but that shouldn't affect the fact that it doesn't show the options

Comment: It does show the options in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-grld5?file=/demo.js).

Comment: does the `id`, `labelId`, `InputLabel`, `FormControl` are 100% required for it to work ?

Comment: The `Select` should display and save the options normally without those. Please add your codesandbox that can reproduce the problem here so everyone can help you.

Comment: god sake you were right it was grabbing the select from react instead of the one from MUI I though the react one was select ... but apparently there's default select (select), react-select (Select) and MUI select (Select) and got all this stuff mix up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use MUI's `Select` but the `Select` in the screenshot is from react-select package. Both component name is `Select` so if you're migrating to the other library, you should use different default name to avoid mixing one with the other:

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'
import MuiSelect from '@mui/material/Select';
```

Comment: yeah thank you wouldn't have notice it if I didn't start making the sandbox I though that there were only 2 selects and that the react one was the one with small s(select)